# Android: OnEditorActionListener is not being fired for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I press a button, is makes the EditText visible.
When I start typing into the EditText, it never prints out anything to the logcat.  I am using the built in soft keyboard on a samsung galaxy nexus.

`textbox_group_name` is the `EditText`.
Why is the function not being called?

```
            create_group_button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    textbox_group_name.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                }   
            });


            textbox_group_name.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent key) 
                {
                    Log.i( "MY_TAG", "Typing group name" ); //never prints

                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ) 
                    {
                        Log.i( "MY_TAG", "Submitting group name" ); //never prints
                        new_group_name = textbox_group_name.getText().toString();
                        String packet = GCPPacket.generatePacket( GCPPacket.TYPE_CREATE_ROOM, currentUser.id(), new_group_name);
                        sendRequest( packet );

                        displayLoadingScreen();

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you actually tapping on the action button?

Comment: @CommonsWare What is this action button? This is what the soft keyboard looks like on the phone:https://www.google.com/search?q=android+soft+keyboard+action+button&biw=1093&bih=534&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=VdLoVLbQL8SrgwTwv4A4&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=samsun+galaxy+soft+keyboard&imgdii=_&imgrc=qNNtkvjpy-b3TM%253A%3B56nJx_-OiS5ZzM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.larrysworld.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F04%252Fsamsung-keyboard.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.larrysworld.com%252Fsamsung-apple-make-war-and-love-and-both-have-great-tablets%252F%3B614%3B196

I am pressing the return arrow

Comment: If you have a "return arrow", then presumably you have a multi-line `EditText`. In that case, there may not be an action button on all keyboards (such as the screenshot you linked to), and your `OnEditorActionListener` will not be invoked. On single-line `EditText` widgets, where that "return arrow" would appear, I would expect to see something like "Next" or "Done" -- that would be the action button.

Comment: @CommonsWare
I added  `android:maxLines="1"`, and it still shows the return arrow.  So I guess my real problem is that `Next`/`Done` aren't showing.

Comment: Have you used `android:imeActionId` or `android:imeActionLabel`?

Comment: @CommonsWare
I had to add `android:inputType="text"` to the XML for the EditText.
The only reason I even tried this was because my login screen works just fine and I'm using similar xml and code for this group chat feature.   And the only significant attribute I left out was the inputType.  If you want to post a more detailed answer or explain why this was needed, I'll accept it.  Thanks for helping me figure it out and realize I just needed to get that action button showing.